# Unpacking a nested matrix in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've got some data like

```
moved_to_matrix    [[0, 1, 0]]
companies          [Barcelona, Madrid, Amsterdam]
moved_from_matrix  [[0, 0, 1]]
```

And I want to figure out how to convert this to a transition matrix in Pandas/Numpy. Has anyone any ideas. I tried pd.melt but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: data are in file? Or it is 2 column dataframe?

Comment: Originally in a dict - but I've put it into a pandas dataframe with two columns.

Comment: so need from second column  create 3 columns?

Comment: I need something like ```Barcelona

Comment: can you edit question? because bad format of comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['moved_to_matrix','companies','moved_from_matrix'],
                   'b':[[[0, 1, 0]], ['Barcelona', 'Madrid', 'Amsterdam'], [[0, 0, 1]]]})

print (df)
                   a                               b
0    moved_to_matrix                     [[0, 1, 0]]
1          companies  [Barcelona, Madrid, Amsterdam]
2  moved_from_matrix                     [[0, 0, 1]]

#remove nested list
df.b = df.b.mask(df.b.str.len() == 1, df.b.str[0])
print (df)
                   a                               b
0    moved_to_matrix                       [0, 1, 0]
1          companies  [Barcelona, Madrid, Amsterdam]
2  moved_from_matrix                       [0, 0, 1]

#create columns by df constructor
df = pd.DataFrame(df.b.values.tolist(), index=df.a).reset_index()
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
print (df)
                   a          b       c          d
0    moved_to_matrix          0       1          0
1          companies  Barcelona  Madrid  Amsterdam
2  moved_from_matrix          0       0          1
```